# Self employed contractor - profiles in Linkedin etc

Tags: self-employment

I am now a self employed developer working as a contractor for multiple companies, and they don't necessarily know about the others (as they shouldn't). I have my name as the sole proprietor and get hired under such.

What would be the best way for me to list what I work with and what services I provide? Should I mention these companies by name - I thought no because I still want to keep them separate but at the same time I want to put out there my skills and experience so the next potential client can reach me.

Comment: It might be worth reading the contracts of each company - there's a chance you've signed to say that you'll solely work for them. If that's the case, then definitely do not list them all (or any) on your LinkedIn profile.

Comment: Have you signed [NDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement)s as well? You may find you can't reference the company you are working for, until you have completed the work done for said company.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO. you can list the technologies and project types you worked with.

Also, portfolio of examples and interesting solutions would be nice addition to an interview, 
especially, if your work is done for Web / Cloud.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as the OP and this is what I do as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would only mention them by name with specific authorisation from them, and I would only request that authorisation in circumstances where I felt it was very beneficial to me (EG, if I helped launch a specific product that became very well known).  In addition to not having them find out about each other, you could be accidentally divulging details about their internal operations that they prefer be kept private.

Instead, refer to the companies in broader terms of their industry, role and size. EG: "A mid-sized financial services company focused on boutique investments...",  "A large book publisher with several hundred employees across four north american offices...", "An international distributor of speciality food products.."

This frees you up to tell a "story" that outlines what you bring to each company, but without needing to name them and risk any liability that might bring.

Comment: That makes sense. Now the next challenge is how best to list them concurrently as my current engagements.

Comment: unfortunately linkedin seems to have a very traditional "employee" focused model, I find it hard to manage my profile effectively as someone working in a "business to business" capacity

Answer (score 1):

From a UK stand-point, one thing to note is that whilst you really ought to get permission off the companies if you plan to use them as portfolio items on a company website (eg. under "Clients", or "Businesses We've Worked With". I have been asked before to remove logos and company names from portfolio and case-study pages on my various business websites), but you don't need to get permission to include the companies on your CV itself. This is purely a presentational difference, but it matters.

Therefore it's worth considering what you're actually constructing here: are you just fleshing out your CV, or are you drafting your business website?

Comment: It is mostly for advertising my services. I'd like to show all the good work I did for very preeminent companies without necessarily disclosing who they are and attract new clients. I agree the details could go on a CV or disclosed to prospective clients.

Comment: @user1220 Therefore could you describe them as something like "FTSE 100 Financial Services Company" on your LinkedIn profile, but then when you're talking to new clients actually have a one-sheet with your various portfolio items on it, mentioning the actual names. I think the company labelled thing has to stress the size of the business ideally, in terms of revenues, as it's the most likely thing to get eyeballs on your profile.